# SSIS Package Stuck in "Pending Execution" status

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-administration

After doing a restart to fix some performance issue on a 2017 SQL Server, couple of jobs (kicking off SSIS package) have been failing, all stuck pending execution state. Same issue persists when I manually start the job or execute the package from SSISDB.

The job is set to run using SQL Agent Service, other jobs running a T-Sql statement have been running fine.

Comment: have you checked in services manager that SSIS Service is running?

Comment: Yes it's running, just checked again

Comment: If the packages are running as part of a SQLAgent job, check the job for what user it's running as. Check those permissions, and that could be your problem.

Comment: The job is using SQL Server Agent Service Account, I don't think this is where the problem is because when I execute the package directly in SSISDB, I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a permission issue but still don't understand how and why, no changes were made on the server, I was also unable to deploy SSIS package from VS to SSISDB/Integration Services Catalogue.

Repairing the SQL Server via the installation centre seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Wow! So glad you ran across this! I had the exact same issue and the repair was the only thing that fixed it. The one thing I was confused about is when I open the Installation Center, it wanted me to point to the SETUP file. After some poking around, I found it at "D:\SQLinstall\Evaluation_ENU" (if anyone else runs into this). My SQL Server was preinstalled. Just thought I would share if it might help anyone else.

Comment: Running a SQL repair also works for me, but the problem then comes back within a few days, making me think it must be a GPO policy issue.